# Update table using SELECT on combined columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to update a column in on of my tables with an id that is the combination of a few characters from two other columns within the same table. Currently as I have it written it fails, because it won't allow multiple values to be return in the subquery. How can I get this to work?

Here is what I have.

```
UPDATE Users
SET AccountId = (
                  SELECT RIGHT(lastName, 5) + RIGHT(UserId, 6)
                  FROM Users
                )
```

I'm trying to end up with something like:

```
AccountID

lliams994521

ohnson103297
```

....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do a `SELECT` if the `UPDATE` is based on fields of the *same record*:

```
UPDATE Users
SET AccountId = RIGHT(lastName, 5) + RIGHT(UserId, 6)
```

Comment: Wow that was simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do something like this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET AccoundId = (SELECT RIGHT(lastName, 5) + RIGHT(UserId, 6) FROM users AS SubUsers WHERE SubUsers.UserId = MainUsers.UserId)
FROM Users MainUsers
```

In your case this doesn't make any sense. As @GiorgosBetsos mentioned

> You don't need to do a `SELECT` if the `UPDATE` is based on fields of the
>   same record